# Google Play Services Version Difference between Emulator and Current

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services

I have been trying to simply have my app get the current location of the user, but I cannot get past the google play services error. I have Google API 22 x86 and Google Play Services installed on the emulator. This is what my dependencies look like in my gradle.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.+'
}
```

The one thing I did notice was when I went into settings and looked at the version of the Google Play Services *while in the emulator* was that it was version 6.7.74. However, when I tried switching the dependencies to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.7.74'
```

I received errors elsewhere in my code. Particularly when calling methods related to the location API.

Comment: What's the error you get? Can you update Google Play Services on your emulator?

Comment: @Andy It's the error that says "Update Google Play Services. ___ Wont run unless you update Google Play services" I've tried the version on the emulator and the version my phone currently has and the 7.5.0 found on google's dev site.